# A word for 'sampler' suitable for international readers

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

For a large software package we are providing a small program giving small reference examples of [how to use] the capability of the main product.  My mental image I have of this is akin to a needlework [sampler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampler_%28needlework%29) (typically showing the alphabet font and some reference patterns).

For a modern technical audience the word *sampler* is unsuitable because of:

- ambiguity with an audio sampler and other hi-tech derivatives of *sample*
- the antiquity of the application of *sampler* I'm trying to convey - even for most Western colleagues it is meaningless
- The audience is likely to be Asian, so needs to be something a non-native speaker of English would at least recognise for what it is

Immediate suggestions were:

- *Demonstrator* but that has connotations of showing off the most exciting elements, not providing a reference set. It's a story not an alphabet.  We will be separately providing a set of demos.
- *Examples*, *Illustrations*, *Specimens* all suggest a complete unit (again a 'story' using my analogy, and not necessarily using all the letters of the alphabet). In any case I need a single name for a collective package.  I want to provide one sampler to show many minimalist examples.

Other collective words such as *compendium* or *collection* again fall foul of the implication that each entry is complete and not just a sample fragment.  *Library* also suffers from this, in addition to being ambiguous in the software world.

In summary, I'm looking for a word that suggests a **single** package of **multiple** minimal examples.  Any suggestions?

---

Edit:  For the avoidance of doubt I want a word for the collective, not the contents, therefore any plural word is not going to be suitable for my needs.  We've considered (and rejected) *anthology* and *digest* but something along those lines would be good.

Edit 2: Apologies, I'd assumed it would be taken as read that the software will have user manuals, data samples, training material, demos and example applications.  My problem is that this "sampler" needs a name that makes it distinct that it **isn't** one of the others.

Comment: Would just the word [*samples*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/sample) work for your purpose?

Comment: @JLG Thanks but no. It's a plural and I'm specifically looking for a singular name for the collection-of-samples.  Think more along the lines of *anthology*, *digest*, etc. (which have already been rejected here.)

Comment: How about _taster_?

Comment: Then it’s a *samples collection*. These futile hunts for single words defeats the entire purpose of language, which is about using grammar to combine multiple words in infinitely many semantically significant ways.

Comment: Call it what you will, I believe you will have to define the term to make clear your unique meaning. Terms that could work are: "specimen set," "exemplars," or actually I think "sampler" can work as well as anything you will come up with that has the same meaning.

Comment: _user guide_ or _manual_?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall *Taster* is in the right direction, thanks, though it implies (to me) a more try-before-you-buy scenario than one of looking up how I should do 'X'.

Comment: I'm not sure what this thing is but can it be a pilot version? For example, you can read an [example](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ltscnnct/v2r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.lc_2.0_IC/c_install_pilot_overview.html) here. Other than that, why not simply call it a "reference"? or a "[handbook](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/handbook)" (there are interesting synonyms such as "vade mecum" and "enchiridion" also). I can give as an answer if any of them fits to your idea.

Comment: @ermanen *handbook* or *reference* is in the right direction.  The challenge here is a name that is free of preconceptions; *Software handbook* has too many already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider *recipe book* or *cook book*.

They show you how to do various tasks, but not all tasks, and not all variations of a task..

Comment: Oh, I *do* like cook book.  Your reasoning is spot on.

Comment: + Answer.  No-one has provided better, and it exactly meets the criteria.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the term **[primer](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/primer)**

> a small introductory book on a subject

While this term has been traditionally applied to a physical book, there is no reason it could not be used with digital materials.

You also could consider **[cheat sheet](http://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=cheat%20sheet&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)** (sometimes written *cheat-sheet*)

> A document containing summarized information used for quick reference

Note that this latter term is often applied to a forbidden aid used to cheat on exams.

Comment: These are good candidates, thanks +1. That I effectively have a 'primer' section to the User Manual already is something I could work around. *Cheat sheet* is rather more the function of the item - a set of small reference items to copy from, but *primer* sounds more professional.